# Jumping to C++ error works in VSCode when using cl, but not clang-cl (using the -FC flag)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, cl, clang-cl

I have the following line for a simple build:

```
cl -FC "../main.cpp" /link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

If there is an error in the program, I can alt/ctrl-click the error, and jump right to it. However, if I change the build line to the following, it doesn't jump to the error, and instead pops up "../main.cpp" at the top in the command palette, and says "No matching results":

```
clang-cl -FC "../main.cpp" /link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

I'm not sure if this is caused by some VSCode setting, or if it's something I need to add to clang-cl

Comment: Yeah this happens to me too - VSCode gets confused on file location some of the time. I was able to tab down and then remove the ".." and then it found the file - annoying but it works. And then at some point it just starts finding the files again (again annoying but hey...)

Comment: @DavidBien Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, changing the ".." doesn't appear to have solved the problem. It seems it is able to find the file, but for whatever reason, it's not jumping to the actual line in the file when using `clang-cl` to compile vs using `cl` to compile (in which case, it jumps just fine)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the problem. Yeah and that happens to me too sometimes - haven't figured that one out yet.